# create an instance for a pointer in other scopes

Tags: c++, pointers

I have two methods to create an instance for a pointer.
But one of them will fail.

```
class A {
public:
    int num;
};

void testPointer1(A* a){
    a = new A();
    a->num = 10;
}
A* testPointer2(){
    A* a = new A();
    a->num = 10;
    return a;
}
void testPointer() {
    A* a1 = NULL;
    testPointer1(a1); // this one fails
    //cout << a1->num << endl; // segmentation fault

    A* a2 = NULL;
    a2 = testPointer2();
    cout << a2->num << endl;
}
```

why is testPointer1 wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is valid, but it doesn't do what you want because `testPointer1()` is operating on a *copy* of the pointer, not the actual pointer itself. So when you assign the address to the newly allocated object, it gets assigned to the copy, not to the original `a1` pointer.

Because of this, the address is lost and you get a memory leak. Also, since the original `a1` pointer was never modified in the first place, you attempted to dereference a null pointer, which is a bad thing.

I'd say `testPointer2()` is the better way to do it, but if you want `testPointer1()` to work, try this:

```
void testPointer1(A*& a)
{
    a = new A();
    a->num = 10;
}
```

The parameter type indicates "a reference to a pointer to `A`." That way, instead of a copy of the pointer being passed, a *reference* to the original pointer will be passed. A C++ reference is an alias to another object. So whatever you do on the alias, it gets performed on the original object.

---

**Extra notes:**

Note that the parentheses in `new A();` [are actually significant and their presence or absence makes a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new).

Also note that you must manually `delete` all `new`'ed objects after you're done with them, or you will get a leak. Typically you would wrap the pointer in its own class and implement [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) or use a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) such as [Boost's smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) or [`auto_ptr`](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm), for proper memory management and exception safety.

If you're going to set the value of `num` on initialization, why not create a constructor?

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int n) : num(n) {}
    int GetNum() const { return num; }
private:
    int num;
};

void testPointer1(A*& a)
{
    a = new A(10);
}  

A* testPointer2()
{
    return new A(10);
}

// auto_ptr example, see link in second note above
std::auto_ptr<A> testPointer3()
{
    return auto_ptr<A>(new A(10));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `testPointer1` functions works on a *copy* of the provided pointer : modifications to `a` in `testPointer1` are not reflected to the caller.

It's exactly like in this simpler example :

```
void testInt1(int i)
{
    i++;
}

void testInt()
{
    int i = 0;
    testInt1(i);
    // i is still 0
}
```

If you want the change in `testInt1` to be reflected to the caller, you have to pass either a pointer or reference to `i` (and not just the *value* of `i`). The same solution can be applied to your specific case, though one could argue that pointers to pointer and references to pointer are not really a best practice.

Comment: +1: I like the way you broke it down to illustrate the exact issue - cool!

Answer (score -1):

Is this homework ?

This seems to be obvious:
formal parameters are saved on the stack & restored after method/function call.

then whatever f(type x), manipulating x inside the function/method won't change it's value outside of the function.

even if type is a pointer type.

the only way to make x change inside a function is to tell it is modifiable through references or pointer to type.

in your case :
A* a1 =NULL
call to your method won't change value of a1 outside of testPointer1
so a1 will still be NULL after the call.